# Adding an event listener to an iframe

Tags: javascript, dom, iframe, extjs

Is it possible to add an event listener to an iframe? I've tried this code, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].contentWindow.window.document.body.addEventListener('afterLayout', function(){
                console.log('works');
            });
```

I've also just tried using getting the element by id and adding my listener via the JavaScript framework I'm using, like this:

```
Ext.fly("iframeID").addListener('afterLayout', function(){ alert('test'); });
```

I can call functions in the iframe, so I don't think security is an issue. Any ideas?

Comment: What exactly fires "afterLayout" event?

Answer (score 12):

I never tried to handle 'afterLayout' event but for more browser compatible code
you'll use (`iframe.contentWindow || iframe.contentDocument`) instead of `iframe.contentWindow` .

try something like

```
var iframe = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0],
    iDoc = iframe.contentWindow     // sometimes glamorous naming of variable
        || iframe.contentDocument;  // makes your code working :)
if (iDoc.document) {
    iDoc = iDoc.document;
    iDoc.body.addEventListener('afterLayout', function(){
                        console.log('works');
                });
};
```

Hope it'll help.

Comment: this doesn't work for me! nothing prints out in my console! :/

Answer (score 4):

If you are doing serious iframe work in Ext, you should look into the ManagedIFrame user extension:

http://www.extjs.com/forum/showthread.php?t=40961

It features built-in events and cross-frame messaging, as well as many other benefits.

Answer (score 3):

Reasons for failure could be:-

1. The URL to which the iframe is directed from a different domain as the container, hence code is prevented by cross-domain script blocking.
2. The code is running before the frame content is loaded

Comment: 1) Same domain. 
2) Trying to attach in an onReady event, so the frame content should be ready. Just realized I successfully attached an event listener for load to the iframe, so now I'm really not sure why 'afterLayout' isn't working. Maybe it's a framework issue.

Comment: I think "load" is one of the few events you can listen for early - almost by definition, since you can't properly wait until loading is done without attaching a "load" listener earlier! I found that if you're writing the iframe contents programmatically (e.g. via `srcdoc`) you always have to wait for the "load" event (or jQuery `load()`) before attaching other event listeners will work.