# iframe events in other html

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I'm using an Iframe to have an html file work on a homepage when someone clicks on a link. When I use the html file by itself as a webpage, things like multiple key depressions and such work and are accessible. But they aren't when I access the html via an iframe. 
Is this even possible?

**Edit**

Oh, I have a function in my main.html file, which detects key depressions and plays video files based off of key presses (it's a psuedo video game). It uses eventlisteners and objects to detect positions of keys. But again, this doesn't work when I view it in an iframe from some other html page, index.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First off, if your iframe and parent are on different domains, you're going to have some security issues that you may/may not be able to get around (read [Cross-Domain Communication with IFrames](http://softwareas.com/cross-domain-communication-with-iframes)).

As for how to access your iframe's events from the parent.

See:

- [Adding an event listener to an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394262/adding-an-event-listener-to-an-iframe/1416262#1416262)
- [Add event to iframe body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2387589/add-event-to-iframe-body)
- [Adding click event handler to iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6452502/adding-onclick-event-to-iframe)
- [Adding event handler to an iframe using JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549488/adding-event-handler-to-an-iframe-using-jquery)

**EDIT:** Should mention that your question is a bit ambiguous, so I'm kind of shooting in the dark here with this answer.